# Is there any simple 3D viewer application?

Tags: 3d, image-viewers

I'm frequently working with 3D assets and occasionally I need to quickly preview the asset without opening 3D modelling or game engine software. Most commonly I work with fbx, obj, dae or gltf files.

When I had my windows machine I was using [MS 3D viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_3D_Viewer), but I don't expect that to be on linux. So I'm looking for any simple to use, quick to load software that just draws the imported model and nothing else.

Anybody knows about some?

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

- [f3d](https://f3d-app.github.io/f3d/) but there is no FBX support for now. Install and view a file with:

  ```
  sudo apt install f3d
  f3d mymodel.gltf
  ```
- [Mesh viewer](https://github.com/RBFraphael/meshviewer)
- [Meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net/)
- [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/) (very usefull and fast) (http only)

Comment: Seems you can simply do `apt install open3d-gui` for open3d (22.04)

Comment: Open3D link appears to be broken (HTTPS doesn't work for some reason, while HTTP does).

Comment: Confirmed, can't install properly even after `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Comment: f3d supports FBX now. At least some of them. I had downloaded an FBX, and tried to import it into Blender, but Blender said the FBX version was too old, and F3D could not open the FBX either. I tried another FBX, and F3D opened it.

Answer (score 1):

[`ctmviewer`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ctmviewer.1.html) from the `openctm-tools` package supports the following formats:

- OpenCTM (.ctm)
- Stanford triangle format (.ply)
- Stereolithography (.stl)
- 3D Studio (.3ds)
- COLLADA 1.4/1.5 (.dae)
- Wavefront geometry file (.obj)
- LightWave object (.lwo)
- Geomview object file format (.off)
- VRML 2.0 (.wrl) - export only

Additionally, `ctmconv` helps convert between these formats.

Comment: Very fast, straightforward installation. Thank you!